# How can i run CV_DIST_L2 in opencv 3?

Tags: python, opencv3.0, edge-detection

Code:[Detect Lines Opencv in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184147/detect-lines-opencv-in-object) -> Amid response

Case1:

```
for xxx in contours:
   [vx,vy,x,y] = cv2.fitLine(xxx,cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01)
```

It throws error -

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'cv'

Case2:

```
for xxx in contours:
   [vx,vy,x,y] = cv2.fitLine(xxx,cv2.CV_DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01)
```

It throws error -

> AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'CV_DIST_L2'

I have `opencv 3` installed in my machine. I am not able to debug this error. Please let me know what mistake am I doing?

Comment: Tried cv2.DIST_L2 ?

Comment: Thanks Miki, I just was about to mention the same. Yes, I opencv3, the cmd is cv2.DIST_L2.

Comment: For older cv2 versions, like opencv2.4.8, you will probably have to fall back to cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2

Answer (score 5):

just try DIST_L2 without CV it should work