# filLine method in opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

i have searched about line detection algorithm in opencv

and i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184147/detect-lines-opencv-in-object)  good answer

but i cant understand this mathematical operations

```
lefty = int((-x*vy/vx) + y)
righty = int(((gray.shape[1]-x)*vy/vx)+y)
```

can anyone explain it to me please

i tried to understand anything ,

```
[vx,vy,x,y] = cv2.fitLine(cnt,cv2.cv.CV_DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01)
```

and i have found that x,y is the center of the contour,  but what is vx , vy ???.

Thanks :)

Comment: vy/vx means slope

Comment: @Zhubei-Federer   thanks :)) but can you tell me what is this params after cv.CV_DIST_L2 mean ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying from Opencv [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=fitline#fitline):

> where (vx, vy) is a normalized vector collinear to the line.

If you want to find the angle of the line you simply call:

```
#find angle in degrees
angle = math.atan(vy / vx) * 180 / math.pi
```

Comment: thanks very much but i have another one  question if you know it, what is this params after cv.CV_DIST_L2   mean ??

Comment: DistType is: is the distance used for line fitting, CV_DIST_L2, is the standard unweighted least-squares fit.
It's also written there in the documentation link that I have shared. Also, please refer to this answer it has a good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/15184899/4734439